# How to convert PySpark dataframe columns into list of dictionary based on groupBy column

Tags: arrays, dataframe, apache-spark, dictionary, pyspark

I'm converting dataframe columns into list of dictionary.

Input dataframe has 3 columns:

```
ID  accounts pdct_code
1    100      IN
1    200      CC
2    300      DD
2    400      ZZ
3    500      AA
```

I need to read this input dataframe and convert it into 3 output rows. The output should look like this:

```
ID arrayDict
1  [{“accounts”: 100, “pdct_cd”: ’IN’}, {”accounts”: 200, “pdct_cd”: ’CC’}]
```

Similarly, for ID "2" there should be 1 row with 2 dictionaries with key value pair.

I tried this:

```py
Df1 = df.groupBy("ID").agg(collect_list(struct(col("accounts"), ("pdct_cd"))).alias("array_dict"))
```

But output is not quite as I wanted which should be a list of dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you described (list of dictionary) doesn't exist in Spark. Instead of lists we have arrays, instead of dictionaries we have structs or maps. Since you didn't operate these terms, this will be a loose interpretation of what I think you need.

The following will create arrays of strings. Those strings will have the structure which you probably want.

```py
df.groupBy("ID").agg(F.collect_list(F.to_json(F.struct("accounts", "pdct_code")))
```

`struct()` puts your column inside a struct data type.
`to_json()` creates a JSON string out of the provided struct.
`collect_list()` is an aggregation function which moves all the strings of the group into an array.

Full example:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1, 100, "IN"),
     (1, 200, "CC"),
     (2, 300, "DD"),
     (2, 400, "ZZ"),
     (3, 500, "AA")],
    ["ID", "accounts", "pdct_code"])

df = df.groupBy("ID").agg(F.collect_list(F.to_json(F.struct("accounts", "pdct_code"))).alias("array_dict"))

df.show(truncate=0)
# +---+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |ID |array_dict                                                            |
# +---+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |1  |[{"accounts":100,"pdct_code":"IN"}, {"accounts":200,"pdct_code":"CC"}]|
# |3  |[{"accounts":500,"pdct_code":"AA"}]                                   |
# |2  |[{"accounts":300,"pdct_code":"DD"}, {"accounts":400,"pdct_code":"ZZ"}]|
# +---+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks alot ZygD. I am new lnto Pyspark so terminologies i did not use correctly and thank you again for providing help with the code as well. I was looking similar to this. Happy learning.

Comment: from pyspark.sql import functions as F

schema = "array<struct<accounts:long,pdct_cd:string>>"

df.withColumn("parsed", F.from_json(F.col("array_dict"),schema)) \
    .withColumn("exploded", F.explode("parsed")) \
    .select( "exploded.*")\
    .show()

df.printSchema() shows array_dict as array and element is of sting type. i was trying to reverse the problem. I have input as output dataframe of above mentioned and i want output dataframe as input of above mentioned dataframe. So above problem is flipped.

Comment: It is hard to follow now. It doesn't seem the opposite... In the question, you showed the input dataframe which does not have a column of type array of strings. Please, could you ask a separate question, carefully design the input dataframe and tell what is its `df.printSchema()`. Also, create the desired output and - *very important* - tell what data types do you need. Please operate in Spark terminology, just don't use "dictionary" or "list". "list" in Spark is array, "dictionary" may be a map or a struct, depending on your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I got my solutions. But yeah i'll make sure i'll use right terminologies in spark. Happy learning.